# Not Receiving Email on Airflow Dag Time out

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using Airflow 1.8. I want the Airflow to send email  when DAG times out. Currently it sends emails when the a task times out or when there is a retry. but not when the DAG is timing out.The DAG is intentionally set to run every minute. the tasks 10 seconds but DAG time out is 5 seconds. the dag fails but it doesn't send any email.
here is my code for DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
  'owner': 'airflow',
   'depends_on_past': False,
   'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
   'email': ['email@email.com'],
   'email_on_failure': True,
   'email_on_retry': True,
   'retries': 1,
   'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
   'execution_timeout': timedelta(seconds=60) 
}

schedule = '* * * * *'

dag = DAG('leader_dag', 
default_args=default_args,catchup=False,dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=5), 
schedule_interval=schedule)

 # t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
 t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='sleep 10',
    dag=dag)
```

here is smtp part from airflow.cfg:
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp

```
#[smtp]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to                                                                                                                                                                         
# the airflow.utils.send_email function, you have to configure an smtp                                                                                                                                                                            
# server here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
smtp_host = "***********.amazonaws.com                                                                                                                                                                                                    
smtp_starttls = True                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
smtp_ssl = False                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
smtp_user = user                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
smtp_port = 25                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
smtp_password = password                                                                                                                                                                                      
smtp_mail_from = no-reply@example.com
```

Comment: have you configured email [SMTP settings](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L344)?

Comment: @y2k-shubham, yes. I did. and I already received email on retry and failure but NOT when whole DAG  times out.

Comment: can you add a 'email_on_timeout': True parameter by any chance ?

Comment: @VincentChalmel, there is no email_on_timeout attribute to my knowledge